# High power jumping mechanism in small robots

Tags: mobile-robot, mechanism, power

I recently saw this video on YouTube featuring a jumping robot: [5 Fastest Robots In The World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b4ZZQkcNEo)

I was curious how this is accomplished mechanically? Do they wind a strong spring or use some sort of air powered piston?

Comment: one more side question, is there a more "scientific" term for propane powered ram? i only find ram trucks that run on propane :P

Comment: i think that it is just a pneumatic cylinder .... it may have the combustion chamber built in or it may be separate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it uses a propane powered ram to launch itself into the air.

The end of the piston is visible in the back of the vehicle.

This webpage states that source of power is battery and propane

https://bostondynamics.com/sandflea

Also found this patent for a combustion powered linear actuator.

https://patents.google.com/patent/US7263955B1/en